# Error when loading jQuery: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of null "

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a bookmarklet that requires jQuery and have run into a problem on a website.

When I try loading jQuery on [toysrus.com](http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=21973566&cp=2255956.2273442.2255964.20469696.19948766&parentPage=family), using this code:

```
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.onload=function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
}
element.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

This error is shown in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of null
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNLaN.png).

The error points to the second line of code in the file:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
```

From what I understand, it's perfectly fine to load jQuery more than once as long as `noConflict()` is called, which I'm doing, and this error only seems to be happening on this one website.

Why is the error occurring and what can I do to fix it?

UPDATE:

Running the code from the line the error is occurring on in the browser causes the same error:

```
typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object"
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of null
```

I'm confused why the error is being thrown, since if `module.exports` doesn't exist, should the console just output `undefined`?

Comment: I was not able to repro this, ran you script and all loads fine

Comment: @workabyte It happens to me in IE11 and Chrome 37. I haven't tried any other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's arguably a bug in jQuery, you should file a bug for it.

For historical reasons, `typeof null` in javascript results in `object`, so their check would throw the exact exception that you're seeing in the case that `module` is null.

If you inspect the value of `window.module` on that site, you'll see that it is null, so it's hitting the case that I'm referring to.

You could even make a pull request ( after filing the bug! ) since the fix is just to change the check to something like

`typeof module === "object" && module && typeof module.exports === "object"`